# Number of Occurrences of a Substring in a String (Java)

Tags: java, string, substring, equals

My goal, in Java, is to return true of the number of occurrences of "cat" in a string is equal to the number of occurrences of "dog".

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
   int matches = 0, matches2 = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-2; ++i)
   {
     if(str.substring(i,i+3)=="cat")++matches;
     if(str.substring(i,i+3)=="dog")++matches2;
   }
  if(matches==matches2)return true;
  return false;
}
```

It always returns true(probably not incrementing counters) unless str is exactly "dog" or "cat". Why?

Comment: Ah, messed around a bit and found that you need .equals("cat"), not ==.

Comment: You've got it.. .equals not ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, messed around a bit and found that you need .equals("cat"), not ==.

Comment: you might also use `.toLowerCase()` otherwise you wont find "Cats" or "DOGS!".

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing strings with `==`, while you should use `.equals(..)`.

In addition there is no need to scan the strings one character each. Just use

```
public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

So that you can skip many more characters per step. Eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); /* do nothing */)
{
  int x == str.indexOf("dog", 0);
  if (x == -1)
  {
    // no more occurrences
  }
  else
  {
    i = x + "dog".length();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea seems to be right but comparisons of strings used to be tricky. Try

```
if(str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat")) ++matches;
```

Greetings 
Ralf